ExtentsReports child node get start and end time method issue
enter image description hereExtentSparkReporter htmlReporterSuite = createHtmlReporter(randomFilePath);
            extent = new ExtentReports();
            extent.attachReporter(htmlReporterSuite);

            ExtentTest parentNode = extent.createTest("ParentNode");

            ExtentTest childNodeOne = parentNode.createNode("ChildNodeOne");
            childNodeOne.pass("New passs");
            childNodeOne.getModel().setStartTime(new Date(1732256983094L));
            childNodeOne.getModel().setEndTime(new Date(1732256992702L));

            childNodeOne.info("Manually Start - " + new Date(1732256983094L) + ", End - " + new Date(1732256992702L));
            childNodeOne.info("Getted Start - " + childNodeOne.getModel().getStartTime() + ", End - " + childNodeOne.getModel().getEndTime());

            WaitTime(10);

            ExtentTest childNodeTwo = parentNode.createNode("ChildNodeTwo");
            childNodeTwo.pass("New passs");
            childNodeTwo.getModel().setStartTime(new Date(1732257143285L));
            childNodeTwo.getModel().setEndTime(new Date(1732257456500L));

            childNodeTwo.info("Manually Start - " + new Date(1732257143285L) + ", End - " + new Date(1732257456500L));
            childNodeTwo.info("Getted Start - " + childNodeTwo.getModel().getStartTime() + ", End - " + childNodeTwo.getModel().getEndTime());

            extent.flush();

This is my code and output is

ExtentReport version - 5.1.2
How to set the customised end time for child node.
